# Beautiful Soup & Python, Nested Elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape nested elements via BeautifulSoup and I have been pulling my hair out for a couple days now.  I am, by far, a novice -- so I hope the simplicity of this question does not offend anyone.  Still, any help in any capacity would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html I'm attempting to scrape.

```
        <div id="specs" class="pane">
           <div class="col">
              <ul class="list">
                 <li>
                    <ul>
                       <li><b>width</b>2</li>
                       <li><b>length</b>1</li>
                       <li><b>color</b>blue</li>
                       <li><b>metal</b>steel</li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
```

And in a perfect world, here is my result...

```
width, 2
length, 1
color, blue
metal, steel
```

While I've come close, I know now this can't be the answer...yet, at the same time, I can't seem to loop through the li elements.

```
div = div.find("div", {"id":"specifications"})
result = [i for i in div.find('li')]
```

If anyone can just push a a beginner in the right direction, it would be greatly greatly appreciation, and thank you in advance for any insight!

Comment: Can you show the full start of the code where you make the beautifulsoup object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector via `select()` to find the target `b` elements, for example :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw = '''<div id="specs" class="pane">
           <div class="col">
              <ul class="list">
                 <li>
                    <ul>
                       <li><b>width</b>2</li>
                       <li><b>length</b>1</li>
                       <li><b>color</b>blue</li>
                       <li><b>metal</b>steel</li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, "lxml")

result = soup.select("div#specs b")    
for r in result:
    print r.get_text(), r.next_sibling
```

**output :**

```
width 2
length 1
color blue
metal steel
```

---

The following is a pure `lxml.html` alternative for comparison (since OP seems interested in `lxml`, judging from his comment below). The output is exactly the same as BS snippet above.

```
from lxml import html
raw = '''assume the same XML as in the previous snippet'''
root = html.fromstring(raw)

result = root.cssselect("div#specs b")
for b in result:
    print b.text, b.tail
```

`lxml` supports both XPath (via `xpath()`) and CSS selector (via `cssselect()`), and [`lxml` is fast](https://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0).

Comment: har07, I have been having issues getting lxml to work on my machine, but the simplicity of what you provided convinced me (especially as a novice), I need to go this route.  Everything now works perfectly, I'm excited to start using LXML, and so a big thank you for your help!!